# XMLMASSUPDATE MSBUILD Tigris Tasks

Tags: msbuild, xmlmassupdate, tigris

I am trying to set the compiler options attribute from a value to blank using the msbuild task of xmlmassupdate.  Unfortunately it is only changing the c# (the first one) and not the second one.  Does anyone know the syntax for xmlmassupdate to do this?

Comment: alternate ways to change this attribute using msbuild are also welcome

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems similar to the one described in here:
[Stack overflow: MSBuild XmlMassUpdate Task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444366/msbuild-xmlmassupdate-task).

Basically, when you have more than one child node inside a parent, you have to provide a key by which the update is going to find your node using xmu:key attribute like:

```
 xmu:key="nameOfTheAttribute"
```

where nameOfTheAttribute is the attribute that's identifying the child node